# Python ODBC Create Table IF Not Exists

Tags: python, sql, odbc

I have a SQL ODBC statement in Python but it always returns an error.  On the SQL Server the statement works fine.  Can anyone help me here?

```
execute("IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name='tablename' AND xtype='U')
            CREATE TABLE tablename (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, fieldA NVARCHAR(Max) NOT NULL, fieldB NVARCHAR(Max) NOT NULL)")
```

Comment: Could you please provide the error and the code you use to execute the SQL command? As you point out, the SQL statement itself is fine, so the error must lie in the python code used to execute it

Comment: execute("IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name='tablename' AND xtype='U')
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: I'm assuming the quotation marks are incorrect for the Execute in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Please note that you have to use triple quotations for multi-line string in Python, if the execute statement is pasted above as written in your script it most likely fails from the newline.

```
execute("""IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name='tablename' AND xtype='U')
        CREATE TABLE tablename (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, fieldA NVARCHAR(Max) NOT NULL, fieldB NVARCHAR(Max) NOT NULL)""")
```

I recommend just using the pandas [to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) function. It will create the table with all necessary columns in case it does not exist.

You can use the **if_exists** parameter to handle an already existing table ('append'/'replace'/'fail')